# Snake game unexpected lag

Tags: c#, lag, 2d-games

I have created a small section of code which create a very basic snake game( it is not completed yet ).
But It seems to be lagging in an odd way. In the start of the game, everything is smooth but as I turn the game is drastically becoming laggier and laggier.

(By the way : I know I don't need to redraw every frame but I feel like it is more generic like that and I know the problem does not lie there)

```
namespace Snake
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region variables

        static List<Snake_part> parts;
        static List<Turn> turns;

        System.Timers.Timer _timer;
        static Graphics g;

    #endregion

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        g = this.CreateGraphics();

        parts = new List<Snake_part>();
        turns = new List<Turn>();

        parts.Add(new Snake_part("Right",new Rectangle(50,10,25,25)));
        parts.Add(new Snake_part("Right", new Rectangle(24, 10, 25, 25)));

        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(30);
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        turn();
        changePos();

        draw();
    }

    static private void draw()
    {
        try
        {
            g.Clear(Color.Black);
        }
        catch { }
        foreach(Snake_part part in parts)
        {
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, part.Rect);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) { turns.Add(new Turn(parts[0].Rect.X, parts[0].Rect.Y,"Left")); }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) { turns.Add(new Turn(parts[0].Rect.X, parts[0].Rect.Y, "Right")); }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) {
            turns.Add(new Turn(parts[0].Rect.X, parts[0].Rect.Y, "Up"));
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) { turns.Add(new Turn(parts[0].Rect.X, parts[0].Rect.Y, "Down")); }
    }

    static private void turn()
    {
        if(turns.Count >= 1){
            foreach (Snake_part part in parts)
            {
                if (turns.Count >= 1)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        foreach (Turn turn in turns)
                        {
                            if (part.Dire == "Right")
                            {
                                if (part.Rect.IntersectsWith(new Rectangle(turn.X + 25, turn.Y, 1, 1)))
                                {
                                    part.Dire = turn.Dire;
                                    if (part == parts.Last())
                                    {
                                        turns.Remove(turns.Last());
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else if (part.Dire == "Down")
                            {
                                if (part.Rect.IntersectsWith(new Rectangle(turn.X, turn.Y + 25, 1, 1)))
                                {
                                    part.Dire = turn.Dire;
                                    if (part == parts.Last())
                                    {
                                        turns.Remove(turns.Last());
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else if (part.Dire == "Up")
                            {
                                if (part.Rect.IntersectsWith(new Rectangle(turn.X, turn.Y - 25, 1, 1)))
                                {
                                    part.Dire = turn.Dire;
                                    if (part == parts.Last())
                                    {
                                        turns.Remove(turns.Last());
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else if (part.Dire == "Left")
                            {
                                if (part.Rect.IntersectsWith(new Rectangle(turn.X - 25, turn.Y - 25, 1, 2)))
                                {
                                    part.Dire = turn.Dire;
                                    if (part == parts.Last())
                                    {
                                        turns.Remove(turns.Last());
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static private void changePos()
    {
        foreach (Snake_part part in parts)
        {
            if (part.Dire == "Right") { part.Rect = new Rectangle(part.Rect.X + 2,part.Rect.Y,part.Rect.Width,part.Rect.Height); }
            if (part.Dire == "Left") { part.Rect = new Rectangle(part.Rect.X - 2, part.Rect.Y, part.Rect.Width, part.Rect.Height); }
            if (part.Dire == "Up") { part.Rect = new Rectangle(part.Rect.X, part.Rect.Y - 2, part.Rect.Width, part.Rect.Height); }
            if (part.Dire == "Down") { part.Rect = new Rectangle(part.Rect.X, part.Rect.Y + 2, part.Rect.Width, part.Rect.Height); }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you iterate over the entire snake in `turn()`? It seems to me that only the head and the tail should matter.

Comment: No. The whole point is that it will turn the parts only if they arrived at the turn position

Answer (score 0):

Those empty catch blocks are a red flag - you never want to do that...  That isn't a valid way to cache and reuse a Graphics object.   Get a new one each time, and dispose of it.

```
private void Draw()
{
    using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
    {
        g.Clear(Color.Black);

        foreach (Snake_part part in parts)
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, part.Rect);
    }
}
```

In the 'turn' method, you can't remove a Turn from inside a Turn iterator.  It would be better to find a way to mark the Turn as 'done' and clean up at the end.   And there are lots of Turn objects that never get removed - for example just hold the right key down, and you will see the list of Turns build up quickly.

Comment: Hey. I check what you said about the turns and The turns list is at 0 or 1 most of the times. But it gives me this eror : A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll every time I click

Comment: Yes, the InvalidOperationException is "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." which drops you out of the iterator - is that really what you want?  If so, use a 'break;' instead of an exception to exit the iterator.  I put a 'Debug.WriteLine(turns.Count);' at the end of the turn method and found that holding a key down will build up lots of Turns.

Comment: One more comment: you also have a threading problem, too. The KeyDown event (where you add Turns) is on the Main (UI) thread, and the timer callback event is on a worker thread (where you consume and remove Turns).  You probably want both those operations on the same thread (use a different timer, or BeginInvoke the operation to the Main thread), or add locks to prevent reading/writing/deleting from the same collection on different threads.